# Issue in sorting data in hierarchy wise using slicer option

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, slicers

Data considered in matrix

[Rank Slicer selected as 3 but i was getting all sites instead of only rank with 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPmED.png) Details about my data:

i am having table(Table Name: MGR) with columns as Date, Plant Name, Generation, Sp. Yield and i am having day wise geenration data in the table, now i created measure as avg yield where i had considered avg of yield column , based on the values in Sp. yield column and i had created Yield Rank column as

```
Yield Rank = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    MGR[Sp. Yield] > 4, 5,
    MGR[Sp. Yield] >= 3 && MGR[Sp. Yield] <= 4, 4,
    MGR[Sp. Yield] >= 2 && MGR[Sp. Yield] < 3, 3,
    MGR[Sp. Yield] >= 1 && MGR[Sp. Yield] < 2, 2,
    1  
)
```

MY Requirement:

I was using the above Yield Rank column in slicer and now i want to filter the data based on the yield rank selected, now if i select rank as 1 then i want to display the site name with only rank as 1(in hierarchy level like year then month then day)..but now i was getting all sites where values are equal to 1 in any of the date. Also i was getting sum values in month wise data instead of average rank. Attaching the reference pic for understanding where i had selected matrix and i am having data for 1 month and hierarchy followed is site name, Year, Month, day.

Comment: No pic reference in the question above. Sharing a sample pbix will allow us to help you faster.

Comment: Added Relevant pics for better understanding...

Comment: Could you upload a sample pbix, need to explore your data model more. In your relevant pic, is the issue that 5th line shouldn't be displayed? Try removing the measure from the matrix.